# Evernote Access Permission change from Basic to Full

Tags: evernote

while generating Evernote API key I had selected Basic Access permission. Now I would want to change it to Full Permission. How can I do that? Pls. help.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is already in production, [contact Evernote's developer support](https://dev.evernote.com/support/). If you're still sandboxed, then you can probably just autogenerate a new key with Full permissions and use that instead.